# Is this valid when it comes to setting something from an API response in React ? (How do I change data retrieved from an API in react)

Tags: reactjs, json

I have an API giving me response like this:

```
[
{id:1, name:mango, flag: true},
{id:2, name:apple, flag: false},
{id:3, name:banana, flag: false},
{id:4, name:peach, flag: false},
{id:5, name:orange, flag: true},
]
```

Here I have already got the response from the API and stored it in a state value called "getFruits" and then I am trying to modify the data.

I want this API response but want to change the second field from "name" to "fruitname" - How do i do it ? I tried something like this but i think it is wrong.

```
const [getFruits, setFruits] = useState([]); 

const fruitdata = getFruits.map((data) =>   { 
id: data.id;
fruitname: data.name;
flag: data.flag;   }   );
```

In the end, I want a new JSON which will be like this:

```
[
{id:1, fruitname:mango, flag: true},
{id:2, fruitname:apple, flag: false},
{id:3, fruitname:banana, flag: false},
{id:4, fruitname:peach, flag: false},
{id:5, fruitname:orange, flag: true},
]
```

Additionally, If i want to filter this, like
a. Get all the "false" line items only
b. Get ID with 4
..and then assign it to a a new JSON constant, how do i do it ?
like fruitfilteredtrue giving me the below:

```
[
 {id:1, fruitname:mango, flag: true},
 {id:5, fruitname:orange, flag: true},
]
```

**Update:**
*I think it should not be const moreover.*

I tried something like this but when doing this, the return data does not look like.. every line in the JSON gets enclosed by a **fielddata**

```
fielddata = getFields.map((data) => {
  return (
    { 
      id: data.id,
      fruitname: data.name,
      flag: data.flag
    }
  )
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss the `return` statement.

```
const fruitdata = getFruits.map((data) => { 
     return {
         id: data.id;
         fruitname: data.name;
         flag: data.flag;
     }
});
```

This is my working example -

```
const rawData =[
  {id:1, name:"mango", flag: true},
  {id:2, name:"apple", flag: false},
  {id:3, name:"banana", flag: false},
  {id:4, name:"peach", flag: false},
  {id:5, name:"orange", flag: true},
  ]
  
const [getFruits, setFruits] = useState([]); 
useEffect(()=>{
    setFruits(rawData)
},[]);

const fruitdata = getFruits.map((data) => { 
const newObj = {};
newObj.id = data.id;
newObj.fruitname = data.name;
newObj.flag= data.flag;
return newObj;
});

console.log(fruitdata)
```

Comment: I just did it a minute back - thank you so much for responding to this question but please see the "updated" section at the bottom. I am having an issue where the JSON is wrapped by a "fruitdata" for every line due to this.

Comment: Try to do it with create new object inside of the map function.     const fruitdata = getFruits.map((data) =>   { 
    Const newData = {};
    newData.id = data.id;
    newData.fruitname = data.name;
    newData.flag = data.flag;
    return newData;
    });

Comment: Anyway, you can show me how the syntax for it would be ? Sorry for asking..

Comment: This is my working example -
`const rawData =[
  {id:1, name:"mango", flag: true},
  {id:2, name:"apple", flag: false},
  {id:3, name:"banana", flag: false},
  {id:4, name:"peach", flag: false},
  {id:5, name:"orange", flag: true},
  ]
  
  const [getFruits, setFruits] = useState([]); 
  useEffect(()=>{
    setFruits(rawData)
  },[]);
  const fruitdata = getFruits.map((data) =>   { 
  const newObj = {};
  newObj.id = data.id;
  newObj.fruitname = data.name;
  newObj.flag= data.flag;
  return newObj;
     }   );

  
  console.log(fruitdata)`

Comment: Why do you use useEffect here ? Just asking for me to understand this better.

Comment: To avoid re-rendering each time.
Using `useEffect()` with an empty array as the second argument tell this block to invoke just when this component is rendered.
without this it will enter to an infinity loop.
ref : https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_useeffect.asp

Comment: This does not seem to work all the time - at times, I'm not getting any data in the fruitdata and sometimes it comes through. Thoughts ?

Comment: I also get getFruits.map is not a function error..

Comment: Can you share your full code?

Comment: Actually, I made it to work.. I had to convert my data to array and then use map.